# My C code of BFS gives incorrect (absolute nonsense) output

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-algorithm

the algorithm for BFS implemented here is mentioned in Cormen. This code however produces invalid outputs for some reason, even for trivial graphs. Everything up to the creation of the Adjacency list works fine.

Here's the entire code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define size 5

struct node *nodelist = NULL;

struct node
{
    int nodeid;
    int parentid;
    int sourcedist;
    char *color;
};

struct graph *adjlist = NULL;

struct graph
{
    struct listnode *list;
    int count;
};

struct listnode
{
    int nodeid;
    struct listnode *next;
};

struct listnode *createnode(int id)
{
    struct listnode *newnode = (struct listnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct listnode));
    (*newnode).nodeid = id;
    (*newnode).next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

int addtoadjlist(int u, int v)
{
    struct listnode *newnode = createnode(v);
    if((*(adjlist + u)).list == NULL)
    {
        (*(adjlist + u)).list  = newnode;
        (*(adjlist + u)).count++;
    }
    else
    {
        (*newnode).next = (*(adjlist + u)).list;
        (*(adjlist + u)).list = newnode;
        (*(adjlist + u)).count++;
    }
}

int disp(int totalnodes)
{
    int degreesum = 0, i;
    struct listnode *currentnode = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < totalnodes; i++)
    {
        currentnode = (*(adjlist + i)).list;
        printf("\n node %d -> ",i);
        while(currentnode != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d -> ",(*currentnode).nodeid);
            currentnode = (*currentnode).next;
        }
        printf("NULL | Degree: %d",(*(adjlist + i)).count);
        degreesum += (*(adjlist + i)).count;
    }
    return degreesum/2;
}

int dispnodeinfo(int totalnodes)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < totalnodes; i++)
    {
        printf("\n node %d: parent %d| distance from source %d| color %c",(*(nodelist + i)).nodeid,(*(nodelist + i)).sourcedist,(*(nodelist + i)).color);   
    }
}

int *BFSQf;
int *BFSQr;

int ENQ(int x)
{
    if(BFSQr == NULL)
    {
        BFSQr = BFSQf;
        *BFSQf = x;
    }
    else
    {
        BFSQr++;
        *BFSQr = x;
    }
    return 0;
}

int DEQ()
{
    int temp;
    if(BFSQr == NULL)
        return -1;
    else if(BFSQr == BFSQf)
    {
        BFSQr = NULL;
        return *BFSQf;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = *BFSQr;
        BFSQr--;
        return temp;
    }
}

int bfs(int s)
{
    (*(nodelist + s)).color = "G";
    (*(nodelist + s)).sourcedist = 0;
    BFSQr = NULL;               //Empty the Queue;
    ENQ(s);
    while(BFSQr != NULL)
    {
        int u = DEQ();
        struct listnode *currentnode = (*(adjlist + u)).list;
        while(currentnode != NULL)
        {
            int nodeid = (*currentnode).nodeid;
            if((*(nodelist + nodeid)).color == "W")
            {
                (*(nodelist + nodeid)).color = "G";
                (*(nodelist + nodeid)).sourcedist = (*(nodelist + u)).sourcedist + 1;
                (*(nodelist + nodeid)).parentid = u;
                ENQ(nodeid);
            }
            currentnode = (*currentnode).next;
        }
        (*(nodelist + u)).color = "B";
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int totalnodes, choice = 0, u, v, i, s;

    printf("\n Enter the number of nodes in the graph: ");
    scanf("%d",&totalnodes);

    nodelist = (struct node *)malloc(totalnodes*sizeof(struct node));
    for(i = 0; i < totalnodes; i++)
    {
        (*(nodelist + i)).nodeid = i;
        (*(nodelist + i)).parentid = INT_MIN;
        (*(nodelist + i)).sourcedist = INT_MAX;
        (*(nodelist + i)).color = "W";
    }

    adjlist = (struct garph *)malloc(totalnodes*sizeof(struct graph));
    for(i = 0; i < totalnodes; i++)
    {
        (*(adjlist + i)).list = NULL;
        (*(adjlist + i)).count = 0;
    }

    while(choice != 3)
    {
        printf("\n\n 1.) Add Edges. \n 2.) Display \n 3.) Exit. \n Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                    printf("\n Enter source and destination vertices for the edge (starting 0): ");
                    scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);
                    addtoadjlist(u,v);
                    //addtoadjlist(v,u);
                    break;
            case 2:
                    disp(totalnodes);
                    //printf("\n Total edges = %d ",disp(totalnodes));     only for non directed graphs.
                    break;
            case 3:
                    break;
            default:
                    printf("\n Invalid input.");
        }
    }

    BFSQf = (int *)malloc(totalnodes*sizeof(int));
    BFSQr = NULL;               // Queue Empty.

    printf("\n Enter source node to apply BFS: ");
    scanf("%d",&s);
    bfs(s);
    dispnodeinfo(totalnodes);

    return 0;
}
```

For the input: 6 1 0 1 1 0 3 1 1 4 1 4 3 1 3 1 1 2 4 1 2 5 1 5 5 2 3 3

Adjacency list that I get is:

```
 node 0 -> 3 -> 1 -> NULL | Degree: 2
 node 1 -> 4 -> NULL | Degree: 1
 node 2 -> 5 -> 4 -> NULL | Degree: 2
 node 3 -> 1 -> NULL | Degree: 1
 node 4 -> 3 -> NULL | Degree: 1
 node 5 -> 5 -> NULL | Degree: 1
```

which is correct. But the output produced is:

```
 node 0: parent 2147483647| distance from source 984096070| color 
 node 1: parent 1| distance from source 984096072| color 
 node 2: parent 2147483647| distance from source 984096070| color 
 node 3: parent 0| distance from source 984096072| color 
 node 4: parent 2| distance from source 984096072| color 
 node 5: parent 2147483647| distance from source 984096070| color
```

Only the node ids have been assigned correctly rest are all bogus values. I did call displaynodeinfo() right after the initial assignment in main(), like this:

```
   int main(void)
   {
     ....

    nodelist = (struct node *)malloc(totalnodes*sizeof(struct node));
    for(i = 0; i < totalnodes; i++)
    {
        (*(nodelist + i)).nodeid = i;
        (*(nodelist + i)).parentid = INT_MIN;
        (*(nodelist + i)).sourcedist = INT_MAX;
        (*(nodelist + i)).color = "W";
    }
    displaynodeinfo(totalnodes);
    .....
   }
```

Here still i got bogus assignments apart for the nodeids. What's wrong? Please help.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Chances are high that you will find the mistake while creating that.

Comment: dozen of severe C errors, and poor language understanding. First (from long list) compare C strings. This code cannot be improved, but written from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code. For starters, enable all your compiler warnings and take a look at them. In this case, some of them are actually real errors. Below it is a quick explanation of each warning (when compiled with GCC).

Therefore, before trying to debug runtime issues with your code, first verify that you have warning-free code.

---

```
<source>: In function 'dispnodeinfo':
<source>:78:62: warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 4 has type 'char *' [-Wformat=]
         printf("\n node %d: parent %d| distance from source %d| color %c",(*(nodelist + i)).nodeid,(*(nodelist + i)).sourcedist,(*(nodelist + i)).color);
                                                             ~^                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                             %s

<source>:78:72: warning: format '%c' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat=]
         printf("\n node %d: parent %d| distance from source %d| color %c",(*(nodelist + i)).nodeid,(*(nodelist + i)).sourcedist,(*(nodelist + i)).color);
                                                                       ~^
```

These first two warnings are already hinting why you are seeing "bogus values" in your output. Not only the format string has mismatching types, but you are also missing one parameter.

```
<source>: In function 'bfs':
<source>:131:45: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
             if((*(nodelist + nodeid)).color == "W")
                                             ^~
```

This lets you know that comparing a pointer to a string literal is not going to do what you expect. In fact, you should be using a `char`, not a `char *` in your struct; and then using single character literals instead of string literals (`'G'` vs. `"G"`) throughout the code.

```
<source>: In function 'main':
<source>:160:13: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     adjlist = (struct garph *)malloc(totalnodes*sizeof(struct graph));
             ^
```

Here, the compiler warns you about a typo in your type name (`struct garph`).

```
<source>: In function 'addtoadjlist':
<source>:52:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^

<source>: In function 'dispnodeinfo':
<source>:80:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^

<source>: In function 'bfs':
<source>:142:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

The remaining three warnings are about functions that you declared as returning `int` instead of `void`, since they do not return anything.

Comment: An finally, the implementation of the Queue datastructure was also incorrect, in the present code, it behaves like a stack.